# Update graph on click

Tags: d3.js

I want to dinamically update a directed graph with new nodes and edges on click on nodes.
I've started from this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795
but currently I don't know how to deals with the new edges (and arrows) that are weirdly positioned.
https://jsfiddle.net/alfredopacino/z1ppabL0/

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var a = {id: "1"},
        b = {id: "2"},
        c = {id: "3"},
        nodes = [a, b, c],
        links = [],
        NODE_CNT = nodes.length; //the nodes count so long

    links.push({source: a, target: b}); // Add a-b.
    links.push({source: b, target: c}); // Add b-c.
    links.push({source: c, target: a}); // Add c-a.

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(200))
        .force("x", d3.forceX())
        .force("y", d3.forceY())
        .alphaTarget(1)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"),
        link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link");
    // build the arrow.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
        .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

    update();

    function update() {

        // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
        node = node.data(nodes, function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });
        node.exit().remove();
        node = node.enter().append("circle").attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.id);
        }).attr("r", 8).merge(node);
        node.on("click", addNodeAndEdges);

        // Apply the general update pattern to the links.
        link = link.data(links, function (d) {
            return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
        });
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link)
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)"); //-----------------arrow----------

        // Update and restart the simulation.
        simulation.nodes(nodes);
        simulation.force("link").links(links);
        simulation.alpha(1).restart();
    }

    function ticked() {
        node.attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            })

        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });
    }
    function addNodeAndEdges(d) {
        //select(d) references the data, not the element. You need to select(this)
        console.log(this)
        NODE_CNT++;
        nodes.push({id: NODE_CNT});
        links.push({source: {id: NODE_CNT}, target: {id: NODE_CNT - 1}});
        links.push({source: {id: NODE_CNT - 2}, target: {id: NODE_CNT}});

        d3.select(this).attr('r', 20)
            .style("fill", "lightcoral")
            .style("stroke", "red");
        update();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `addNodeAndEdges` function. When you're adding new elements to `nodes` and `links`, you're creating new objects, rather than referencing existing ones. For example, when you push a link having a source of `{id: 1}`, that's not the same as having a source of `a`. When the force simulation sets the `x` and `y` attributes of `a`, the source node of your new link won't also be updated. So the new paths you're adding have no x and y coordinates.

[Here's a fiddle that fixes that](https://jsfiddle.net/Loprhztn/1/), by using consistent references to existing objects in `addNodeAndEdges`.

Comment: It looks like this solves, thanks! In your fiddle the first link `links.push({source: {id: NODE_CNT}, target: {id: NODE_CNT - 1}});` is rendered just for its arrow, but I guess it's matter of wrong indexes. Mine was s a very noob mistake indeed (I thought it was a d3 domain issue..)